# long to wide data restructure in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table which is in long format and I want to re-structure it to wide format. Something similar to case to vars in SPSS. I have the data which is created in long format using **melt**

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(71)
DT <- data.table(town = rep(c('A','B'), each=17),
                 tc = rep(c('C','D'), 17),
                 one = rnorm(34,1,1),
                 two = rnorm(34,2,1),
                 three = rnorm(34,3,1),
                 four = rnorm(34,4,1),
                 five = rnorm(34,5,2),
                 six = rnorm(34,6,2),
                 seven = rnorm(34,7,2),
                 eight = rnorm(34,28,3))

DT1 <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("town","tc"),measure=3:10)

DT1[, `:=` (mn = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE), sdev = sd(value,na.rm = TRUE), uplimit = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)+1.96*sd(value,na.rm = TRUE), lowlimit=mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)-1.96*sd(value,na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(town,tc,variable)][, outlier := +(value < mn - 1.96*sdev | value > mn + 1.96*sdev)]
```

so originally the data had 34 records and we had 8 key variables "one" to "eight". using melt we get a data similar to the one that is generated by above code and column "value" holds the data from the original data. Now on this data we do some computation and create the other variables "mn", "sd", "up", "low", "out". Now this data needs to be merged with the original data which has only 34 records. So I want to re-structure this data so that the restructured data has 34 records and eight variable each for "mn", "sd", "uplimit", "lowlimit", "out". How can I achieve this? I was trying dcast but not very clear of `~` and `+` how to use in the formula.....not clearly mentioned in ?dcast and other notes. Do you have something to share which explains this with an example. can the requirement be achieved using dcast?

Comment: Could you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun, Hi, the expected output should have 34 records with 8 variables for each of "mn", "sd", "up", "low", "out". (mn.one, mn.two, mn.three......) So basically reduce the current 272 records to 34 (8*34 = 272). Also it should contain the "town" and "tc" variables which would be used as key to merge in the original data. Hope this helps to visualize the output data.

Comment: With your example dataset won't be possible to get the desired result, because randomly generated id and measure vars won't uniquely identify cells.

Comment: @mtoto, Hi, the key here is the "variable" column basis which the column would be created in the new data.....`town tc mn.one mn.two mn.three mn.four mn.five mn.six mn.seven mn.eight sd.one sd.two sd.three sd.four sd.five sd.six sd.seven sd.eight.................`

Comment: I understand that, but you won't get 34 records unless you share a dataset that is a **result of melt** not of `rnorm()`.

Comment: @mtoto, here you go, you can create the original data using rnorm() and then convert it long format using melt. Now this long data needs to be converted back to wide format keeping in mind the requirement, the code -

Comment: `library(data.table)
set.seed(71)
DT <- data.table(town = rep(c('A','B'), each=17),
                 tc = rep(c('C','D'), 17),
                 one = rnorm(34,1,1),
                 two = rnorm(34,2,1),
                 three = rnorm(34,3,1),
                 four = rnorm(34,4,1),
                 five = rnorm(34,5,2),
                 six = rnorm(34,6,2),
                 seven = rnorm(34,7,2),
                 eight = rnorm(34,28,3))
DT1 <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("town","tc"),measure=3:10)`

Comment: `DT1[, ``:=`` (mn = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE), sdev = sd(value,na.rm = TRUE), uplimit = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)+1.96*sd(value,na.rm = TRUE), lowlimit=mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)-1.96*sd(value,na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(town,tc,variable)][, outlier := +(value < mn - 1.96*sdev | value > mn + 1.96*sdev)]`

Comment: @akrun, do you have any suggestions for this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have found answer to my question post multiple tries. So basically the key to note is that the original data had to have a unique ID identifier which in this case was not present. So I added sequential unique numbers at the end in variable "unique".

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(71)
DT <- data.table(town = rep(c('A','B'), each=17),
                 tc = rep(c('C','D'), 17),
                 one = rnorm(34,1,1),
                 two = rnorm(34,2,1),
                 three = rnorm(34,3,1),
                 four = rnorm(34,4,1),
                 five = rnorm(34,5,2),
                 six = rnorm(34,6,2),
                 seven = rnorm(34,7,2),
                 eight = rnorm(34,28,3),
                 unique = 1:34)
```

This have me the data with a column having uniqueIDs. Then when converting the data in long format, I have used this unique variable as well in **melt**.

```
DT1 <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("town","tc","unique"),measure=3:10)
```

Then created the new variables that were needed

```
DT1[, `:=` (mn = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE), sdev = sd(value,na.rm = TRUE), uplimit = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)+1.96*sd(value,na.rm = TRUE), lowlimit=mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)-1.96*sd(value,na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(town,tc,variable)][, outlier := +(value < mn - 1.96*sdev | value > mn + 1.96*sdev)]
```

Then when converting this long data to wide format so that I have same number of records as in the original data, I have taken help of this unique variable in **dcast**

```
DT2 <- dcast(DT1,town+tc+unique~variable,value.var = c("mn","sdev","outlier","uplimit","lowlimit"))
```

This gave me the desired output with same number of records (34) as in the original data and created the desired number of columns and each cell having same data as that in the long format.

I hope you all find this useful :)!!